# ¿Java admite el paso de variables por referencia?

Tags: java, método, paso-por-valor, paso-por-referencia

Cuando yo paso un objeto a un método mediante un parámetro, el objeto se pasa por valor o referencia? La duda viene por este código:

```
int a = 2;
cambiar(a);
System.out.println(a);

public static void cambiar(int c) {
    c = 10;
}
```

En el código anterior ya sabía que no iba a modificar a `a` en ningún aspecto a menos que el método devolviera un int y lo guardara. ¿Pero en el siguiente código que ocurre?

```
class otraCualquiera {
    Partidas partidas = new Partidas();
    Ventana ventana = new Ventana();
    Gestor gestor = new Gestor(ventana,partidas);
}

class culquiera {
    private Ventana view;
    private Partidas play;

    public Gestor(Ventana v, Partidas p) {
        view = v;
        play = p;
    }
}
```

La duda principal, porque desde la clase cualquiera puedo moficicar directamente a las otras clases? ( `view.setTitle("View sería un jframe")` ) y desde el primer código que mostré no puedo modificar el `int`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Antes de nada...

En Java no existe el paso por referencia. El paso por valor (o por copia como algunos llaman) es obligatorio.

Dirás **pero yo cuando paso un array por parámetros y lo modifico desde el método al que se lo paso, este cambia, no estoy pasando una copia del array**

Parece ser que mi argumento falla, pero te explico:

Lo que tú almacenas en una variable no primitiva **no es el objeto en sí** sino una dirección o identificador del objeto en el espacio dinámico de memoria. Cuando pasas por parámetros la variable, estás pasando una copia de dicha dirección.

### El caso que has propuesto

Has creado tres objetos del tipo `Partidas`, `Ventana` y `Gestor`.

El objeto `Gestor` almacena en sus atributos la dirección de los objetos `Partidas` y `Ventana` que les has pasado por parámetros. **No se ha creado una copia de los objetos pasados.**

Lo que sí tienes es una copia de la dirección de los objetos. Si tú añades la siguiente línea al constructor de Gestor justo tras las que ya tienes:

```
v = null;
```

Sólo harás que el parámetro `v` ya no almacene la dirección del objeto del tipo `Ventana`. En la clase `otraCualquiera`, la variable `ventana` seguirá teniendo la dirección correcta.

Por tanto, el paso ES SIEMPRE por copia del valor, a diferencia de, por ejemplo, C o C++, donde se permite el paso por referencia. Lo que tienes que entender es que en caso de objetos el valor que almacena una variable es una dirección o identificador del objeto y no el objeto en sí mismo.

---

Si lo que quieres es encontrar una forma de poder modificar una variable de tipo primitivo (como un int) desde otro método al que se la pasas (algo no muy común, pero útil en algunos algoritmo recursivos), una técnica podría ser tener el entero como un array de un solo elemento, así se trataría como un objeto y solo pasarías una copia de su dirección (una referencia en toda regla).

El pensamiento habitual es almacenarlo como objeto `Integer`, pero esta clase es inmutable.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue genial! Muchísimas gracias.

Comment: @MatiEzelQ no entiendo bien la parte de *editar un entero*. Creo que eso podrías colocarlo en una nueva pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza con "editar un entero" quiero decir "modificar una variable int". Escribir a las 5 de la madrugada me hace bailar con las palabras. Está completamente relacionado con su pregunta y tiene cabida aquí. Yo personalmente nunca he tenido la necesidad de pasar tipos primitivos por "referencia". Empaquetarlo en un array de un solo elemento o tenerlo en un atributo de una clase empaquetadora propia permitiría la modificación del mismo desde cualquier método que tenga la referencia al objeto (que es lo que se pasaría por parámetros).

Comment: Eso lo entiendo. Lo que no entiendo es el contexto en el que quiere modificar el entero dentro del método. Por ello, le pido a @MatiEzelQ que cree una nueva pregunta explicando ese problema en particular. Usualmente pensamos que eso debería pasarse como argumento cuando puede estar dentro de los valores de retorno y así facilitar las pruebas unitarias, el debugging y el mantenimiento del (los) método(s). Lo demás que redactas acá lo tengo presente [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197).

Comment: Y personalmente ese truco de usar el array me parece que ensucia el código, hay formas más elegantes de resolver dicho problema. Pero cuando no lo hay, no queda de otra =\

Comment: Luiggi que queres que explique? No entiendo tu duda. Los ejemplos que di antes son inventados..."Lo que no entiendo es el contexto en el que quiere modificar el entero dentro del método."-Luiggi

Comment: @MatiEzelQ ah, pensé que tenías la necesidad de pasar un `int` a un método y *cambiarle el valor* al salir de él. Te proponía que publiques una pregunta nueva explicando tu situación particular para eso y ver cómo puede resolverse. Pero veo que no tienes esa necesidad.

Comment: Claro, era solo un ejemplo inventado. Igualmente si tuviese la necesidad haría que devolviera el int y lo guardaría, nada mas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Coincido contigo, pero no lo veo como forma de ensuciar el código, ya que solo se haría en casos donde la alternativa a usarlo sea más engorrosa. Generalmente queda más "bonito" no usando un array, sino una clase empaquetadora apropiada.

Comment: @Uexkull aún así...

Comment: C tampoco tiene paso por referencia.

Comment: @ninjalj en C se suele trabajar con punteros y direcciones de memoria, siendo muy importantes los operadores * y & entre otros. Precisamente al paso de las direcciones de memoria (como podría ser con & en datos primitivos) es lo que se conoce como paso por referencia. Si tienes alguna otra definición de paso por referencia te agradecería que la comentaras.

Comment: @Uexkull: Paso por referencia es lo que hace Pascal al marcar un parámetro como VAR, o lo que hace C++ al usar una referencia en el prototipo de la función. Lo que se hace en C es _simular_ paso por referencia pasando por valor un puntero a la variable.

Answer (score 3):

Los puntos breves que cabe recordar aquí son que en Java:

1. Sólo existe el paso por valores.
2. Las referencias a los objetos son valores.
3. Los objetos, sin embargo, no son valores.

El segundo punto es uno que causa mucha confusión.  En Java, cuando tenemos la siguiente situación:

```
String saludo = "¡Saludos a todos!";
```

...decimos popularmente que el valor de la variable es un "objeto," pero este modo de hablar es una simplificación cotidiana—una imprecisión conveniente.  Si queremos penetrar al fondo de esta pregunta hay que entender que de la manera que Java funciona, el valor de `saludos` no es el objeto, sino una **referencia** al objeto.  La la variable, la referencia y el objeto son tres cosas relacionadas pero aparte, y hay que fijarse cuidadosamente de cuáles operaciones afectan a cuál y de cuál modo.  Por ejemplo:

1. La asignación (e.g., `saludos = "¡Saludos de nuevo!";`) cambia el valor de la variable.  Pero el valor de la variable en este caso es una referencia, no un objeto.  La asignación no accede a los objetos—funciona estrictamente con las variables y sus valores.
2. Las comparaciones de variables, tales como `a == b` o `a != b`, observan los valores actuales de las variables.  Cuando estos valores son referencias, entonces, observan estas referencias pero no acceden a sus objetos.
3. `null` es una referencia, no un objeto.  Es una referencia sin objeto, por definición.
4. La invocación de métodos (e.g., `saludo.length()`) o referencia a miembros (`objeto.variable`) observa el valor actual de la variable, y accede al objeto que corresponde a esta referencia.
5. El paso de argumentos (e.g., "blablala".equals(saludo)) pasa una copia del valor de la variable.  En este caso es una referencia.  Esto no accede al objeto.

Todos los ejemplos que das se pueden contestar mediante la aplicación estricta de estas reglas.  Por ejemplo:

> La duda principal, porque desde la clase cualquiera puedo moficicar directamente a las otras clases? ( `view.setTitle("View sería un jframe")` )

En este ejemplo que das, contrario a lo que dices, no hay modificación directa de otra clase.  Lo que estas haciendo, en realidad, es:

1. Acceder a la referencia que es valor de la variable `view`;
2. Acceder al objeto de esta referencia;
3. Lamar el método `setTitle` de este objeto, pasándole una referencia al objeto `"View sería un jframe"`.

Esto de por si no modifica nada; si hay modificación es indirectamente, porque el método `setTitle` modifica algo directamente o causa indirectamente tal modificación mediante llamadas a otros métodos.

Si nos fijamos en mi lista de nuevo, el punto #1 es el único mecanismo que verdaderamente modifica el valor de una variable.  Ninguno de los otros puntos tiene el "poder" de modificar nada directamente.  Aunque decir como dices que `view.setTitle("View sería un jframe")` "modifica `view`" es una forma popular y simplificada de describir lo que pasa, en realidad esto no es lo que pasa cuando nos fijamos estrictamente en cómo funcionan las cosas.

Comment: Una forma de explicar la simplificación del lenguaje que comentas en el último párrafo, es que cuando se dice que «_`view.setTitle("View sería un jframe")` "modifica `view`"_», en realidad lo que se quiere decir es que «_`view.setTitle("View sería un jframe")` modifica el objeto referenciado por `view`_»,

Comment: @ninjalj: Pero hablando estrictamente, "modificar un objeto" en realidad quiere decir modificar uno o más **campos** ("fields") del objeto en cuestión.  O en realidad, campos no necesariamente de este objeto, sino de otros alcanzables mediante las referencias en sus campos. Lo que quiero enfatizar es que cuando profundizamos sobre el sentido preciso de "modificar" en Java, lo que encontramos al fondo son las asignaciones de variables; los otros casos que llamamos "modificar" más informalmente se dan porque indirectamente conducen a asignaciones.

Answer (score 0):

No hay referencias en Java. Los parámetros se pasan por copia (variables de tipo básico del lenguaje o por la copia de la dirección donde están alojados) ESTO NO ES PASO POR REFERENCIA !!!!!!!. El pasaje por referencia es crear un alias de una variable u objeto que tenga distinto nombre pero que HAGA REFERENCIA al mismo espacio de memoria. Por ejemplo:

**ESPACIO DE MEMORIA 10**  -> Tenemos al objeto persona1 guardado en este espacio
La referencia sería        -> crear un objeto   personaReferencia que es un alias de persona1.

En conclusión una referencia es como llamar a un espacio de memoria de varias formas sin utilizar recursos de la memoria de manera adicional.

En Java se utiliza la copia. del contenido de la variable o en el caso de un objeto de la dirección de memoria en la cual esta alojado. En ambos casos se copia el contenido de la variable en otra variable O la dirección de memoria de un objeto en otro objeto (Es lo que en C se llama puntero) la diferencia es que Java lo maneja de manera dedicada en cambio en C lo hace el programador directamente.