# Error al tratar de imprimir vectores (cambian sus valores)

Tags: java

Tengo problemas a la hora de imprimir unos vectores.

Debo llenar 2 vectores de 5 posiciones cada uno, luego recorrer esos vectores y si hay valores repetidos intercambiar esos valores repetidos por -1, pero conservando uno de ellos y almacenando ese vector modificado en un vector auxiliar ya que el vector original no se puede tocar.

Ejemplo:

```
vec1={1, 3, 5, 3, 6}   aux1={1, 3, 5, -1, 6}

vec2={1, 2, 2, 3, 5}   aux2={1, 2, -1, 3, 5}
```

El problema es que el código me esta imprimiendo esto
Suponiendo que lleno el vector con estos valores : `vec1={1, 3, 5, 3, 6}, vec2={1, 2, 2, 3, 5}`
imprime:

```
vec1={1, 3, 5, -1, 6}   aux1={1, 3, 5, -1, 6}

vec2={1, 2, -1, 3, 5} aux2={1, 2, -1, 3, 5}
```

pero no se porque ya que el vector vec1 y vec2 nunca lo modifico

```
    public class revisar {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int d1=0, d2=0;
    static int vec1[]=new int[5]; 
    static int vec2[]=new int[5];
    static int aux1[]=new int[5];
    static int aux2[]=new int[5]; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         llenar();
         cdimensiones();
         mostrar();
    }
    public static void llenar(){
         int i;
         for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.println("Ingrese el valor "+(i+1)+" del vector 1");
           vec1[i]=sc.nextInt();
         }

         for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.println("Ingrese el valor "+(i+1)+" del vector 2");
           vec2[i]=sc.nextInt();
         }
         System.arraycopy(vec1, 0, aux1, 0, vec1.length);
         System.arraycopy(vec2, 0, aux2, 0, vec2.length);
    }
    public static void cdimensiones(){
       int i, j, sum=0, k;
       aux1=revrep(vec1);
       aux2=revrep(vec2);
    }
    public static int[] revrep(int array[]){
       int i, j;
       for(i=0; i<=3; i++){
          if(array[i]!=-1){
            for(j=(i+1); j<=4; j++){
                if(array[i]==array[j]){
                      array[j]=-1;
                }
             }
          }
       }

      return array;
    }
    public static void mostrar(){
       int i;
       System.out.print("\n");
       System.out.println("Auxiliar 1 es: ");
       for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.print(aux1[i]+ " ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");

       System.out.println("Vector 1 es: ");
       for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.print(vec1[i]+ " ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");

       System.out.println("Auxiliar 2 es: ");
       for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.print(aux2[i]+ " ");
       }
       System.out.print("\n");

       System.out.println("Vector 2 es: ");
       for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
           System.out.print(vec2[i]+ " ");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola Cat, echa un vistazo a [¿Java admite el paso de variables por referencia?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4259/20001) se explica las diferencias entre paso por valor y paso por referencia.

Answer (score 1):

el problema lo tienes en esta función

```
public static void cdimensiones(){
   int i, j, sum=0, k;
   aux1=revrep(vec1);
   aux2=revrep(vec2);
}
```

La función revrep recibe una copia de la dirección a la que apunta vec1, por lo que si en esta función modificas el arreglo la modificación se mantiene y por eso tienes ese problema que tanto aux1 como vec1 son iguales al final.

Veo que en la función llenar haces una copia de vec1 y lo almacenas en aux1, por lo que la solución es:

```
public static void cdimensiones(){
   int i, j, sum=0, k;
   aux1=revrep(aux1);
   aux2=revrep(aux1);
}
```

Espero que te funcione.